# In which project should we override item:publish event

Tags: helix, events

I am very new to helix principles. I have created the project structure following sample habitat project. 
My requirement is to call an external api when any item ( of a specific template) is published. 
I have found the sample code and config patch details from the below sitecore document. 
https://doc.sitecore.com/SdnArchive/Articles/API/Using%20Events.html

I am not sure about where to create the new project to add the code and how to patch the config by code deployment.

Can I get some help on this ?

Answer (score 5):

### Answer

In your specific use case, Publishing is the Sitecore function that you are interested in.  Therefore, I would create a Helix Module called **Foundation.Publishing** on the Foundation Level, and then add your Event Handler and associated patch configs there.

### Background

Generally speaking, customizations to Sitecore should be contained with the module that needs the customization.

For example, general enhancement modules, like Language Fallback, SEO, or multisite (to name a few) are kept at the Foundation level.  Think of these as architectual elements that can exist and function completely on their own.

For more specific feature based modules that are options for various deployed websites and overall platform, these are to be kept at the Feature level.

And for specific project, website specific, non-shared modules of the website, these exist in the Project level.

For an event handler, such as item:saved, the question is, "Why do you need it? Which function of the business requirements require it?"

For example, say your business requirement is, "when an item gets saved, I want to update a specific Sitecore default field."  Whatever module in the Foundation layer that you have that is handling Publishing or if this is for SEO, then code for the handler would go in one of those modules.

But, say for example you have a Feature module called **CTA Card**, the business requirment is "when I save a CTA Card item, I need to perform some action on the item:saved event".  This would mean that the event handler you need is tied to (or has a dependency on) the CTA Card module. Therefore you would put the handler in the CTA Card module.

### Summary

Put the event handler code in the   module that most cloesly defines ***why*** you need it in the first place.

Keep Helix Dependency pattern in mind.

Comment: Disagree with the characterization of the Foundation layer here. Only reason for it to exist there is if it's a dependency for multiple Features. Otherwise it should be in a Feature module related to the business function it's related to, as you describe w/r/t CTA functionality.